# requesting temporary credentials for aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Currently I have 1 IAM user, and I've hard coded my aws credentials (access key / secret key) locally with `aws configure`. I have my user group setup with a permission to deny users that are not granted a session key with the command similar to: `aws sts get-session-token --serial-number arn:aws:iam::account_number:mfa/user_name --token-code 123456`

While the above command returns temporary access key, secret key, and session token, I still have a hard coded value for the IAM user to be able to do this `aws sts` call. The question is, how do I go about not hard coding user credentials locally so that I can get temporary credentials each time I need a session.

Answer (score 1):

This scenario is normally handled using an "sts assume-role" and having at least 2 amazon accounts.

You will normally have one aws account that holds only users, sometimes connected with federated identities to your company's AD. These users have no permissions on the first account eccept sts assume role permission which allows them to assume roles.

You then create a second aws account that is the one you will be working on. Typically you will have one aws account by environment, but can also be dependent on your organization structure. There is really no "one size fits it all solution".

On your second account you set up a role that can be assumed by the users in your first account. You also attach needed permissions to that role so that they can actually do stuff.

You then distribute the access key / secret keys to your colleagues from the first account and then they do sts assume-role to work on your environment.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

If you really don't want to keep the secret keys in your configuration, you can always have them as env variables.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

Cheers !

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the access key / secret key for the IAM user is still required to perform aws sts get-session-token unless you have a role in place that a user can use to perform role assumption

Comment: Even if they have a role you still need a key pair. The advantage is that you separate your users and your working environment. Even if the keys leak they have no direct permissions associated with them. You can also make them expire / rotate them